# Show $f(z)=i$ given following conditions

Tags: complex-analysis

Suppose $f(z)$ is a polynomial of degree at most 1. $f(0)=i$ and $|f(z)|^2\leq 1+|z|^3 \;\forall z\in \mathbb{C}$.

Show $f(z)=i$ for all $z\in \mathbb{C}$.

We may let $f(z)=az+i$ for some $a\in \mathbb{C}$. Then How to conclude $a=0$ using the inequality?

Comment: Hint: the crucial estimate is not at $\infty$.

Comment: If using Cauchy estimate, for derivative of degree 1, $|f'(0)|\leq \frac{1}{r}\sqrt{(1+r^3)}$. I cannot get $0$ for whatever value $r$ approaches...

Comment: No need for Cauchy estimates or any complex analysis, algebra suffices.

Comment: Ok. But I still cannot see where $z$ should approach in order to get 0 for $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With $f(z) = az+i$, look at $\lvert f(i\overline{a}\cdot r)\rvert^2$ for $r\in\mathbb{R}$ to see that $a\neq 0$ would violate the inequality.